# twig template for specific collection

Tags: forms, symfony, templates, collections, twig

I use twig with Symfony 3. I have nested collections in a form. I want apply a template for one collection and another template for the second collection.

My current template have a block collection_widget and is applied on the 2 collections.

Can I apply this template for the first collection and use the default collection_widget for the second (nested) collection ?

(I think, i must use a specific block name for the fisrt collection instead generic collection_widget but i don't understand how i can use it...)

Comment: You can apply imported theme to one specific field...

Comment: yes but how ? :-)

Comment: yes, the solution is in the block name. See [link] (http://blog.bouzekri.net/2015/02/06/symfony-tips-find-form-theme-override-block-name/)  with a dump(form) you can show "unique_block_prefix" just add "_widget"  and you have the good block name for a specific field (or collection)...

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the twig theme, i used `{% block collection_widget %}` 
but you must use `{% block **unique_block_prefix**_widget %}` to apply theme only of the field (or my collection).

To take  **unique_block_prefix**, you can show `{{dump(form)}}` and find your field in vars or vars.chidren.vars...

The source of the solution : [Find block name](http://blog.bouzekri.net/2015/02/06/symfony-tips-find-form-theme-override-block-name/)